# php form works fine on localhost, but send empty inputs online

Tags: php, mysql, forms, web-hosting

I have some forms in php that upload data into a mysql database. I have already tested on a localhost server with xampp, but when I upload my files into my host ftp,  the forms do not work. I think it has something to do with the fact that I put this file and also the "connect.php" file under password restriction, and that has something to do with the file permissions. I've already granted permission to the user of the database and permission to the file and I also had tried without the password protection, but the result is the same.

So I start to experiment a little and I figured out that the image uploads fine into the database but the other inputs don't, neither the "header" input nor the "article" textarea...  knowing that, I tried to "echo out" these input results but none of them show something unless the image input. I came to the conclusion that my form is sending empty data. Can someone make suggestions as to what is happening and how to fix it? Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slider_upload">

<h1>Slider principal</h1>
    <div class="forma">

    <form action="sliderPrincipal.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p><label for="header">Header</label>
        <input type="text" id="header" name="header" /></p><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1048576" />
        <p><label for="fileupload">File to upload</label>
        <input type="file" id="fileupload" name="fileupload" /></p><br>
        <p><label for="article">article</label>
        <textarea id="article" name="article" rows="26" style="width: 100%;" >Write here</textarea></p><br>
         <button type="submit" name="submit" value"send">Upload File</button>
    </form><br><br>

</div>
</div>

<div class="message">
    <?php 



$file_dir = "../uploaded";

if (isset($_POST['header'])){
$header = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['header']);
$article = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['article']);
}


foreach($_FILES as $file_name => $file_array){
   //echo "path: ".$file_array['tmp_name']."<br />\n";
   //echo "name: ".$file_array['name']."<br/>\n";
   //echo "type: ".$file_array['type']."<br/>\n";
   //echo "size: ".$file_array['size']."<br/><br/>\n";
   //echo "encabezado ".$encabezado;

        if(is_uploaded_file($file_array['tmp_name'])){
        move_uploaded_file($file_array['tmp_name'], "$file_dir/".$file_array['name']) or die ("Your image couldnt be uploaded <br>");   
        $newpath = addslashes("uploaded/".$file_array['name']);
        include "connect.php"; 
        $addfile = "INSERT INTO slider (header, image, article) VALUES ('$header','$newpath', '$article')"; 
        $result = mysql_query($addfile);
        if ( $result === FALSE ) {
            echo "your post could not be uploaded but we already got your image in our files ";
        } else{
            echo '<p style="padding: 20px;"><h1>Your post was successfully uploaded <h2></p><br><br>';

        }


        mysql_close();  

    } else "No file found";


 }

 ?>
</div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to injection and you are using an obsolete API.

Comment: Use your browser tools and see what the request looks like

Comment: @TheBlueDog hey thanks for let me know it, it would be great if you recommend me something, also any idea of why is this happening? is it for the API?